# Running a batch file from windows task scheduler, but hidden or minimized

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am running a .bat file from windows task scheduler every hour, the file is named: `followers.bat`

And contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.php"
```

It is entered in the task scheduler like so:

`program / script:` `C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.bat`

`parameters (optional):` `<blank>`

`Start in (optional):` `C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2`

I tried adding parameter `/min` but that did not seem to work, it flashed a command prompt like it always does.

I searched around but I did not find a concrete answer, I hope right now in 2015 on windows 8.1 there is a clever / easier way to do this, but I am not aware of that. Hence why I am asking you guys :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this. Especially the second answer. http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple VBScript to call the batch file and then use the scheduled task to run the VBScript.

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "batch-file.bat", 0, True
```

Comment: If you were to create a vbs to run the bat that runs a php script, why not just skip the bat and run the php script from the vbs?

Comment: I am going to try this, it's a shame windows has no option straight from the task scheduler, in my opinion. I was really hoping they did and I just missed it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but the code I use to work with windows command line in hidden mode is:

```
<?php
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.bat", 0); // 0 invisible / 1 visible
```

---

## Note:

Make sure Apache is running under the same user as you, otherwise it won't work.

To run the apache as the same user as you, first **Stop the Apache service** and go to, in my case, `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`, open a command prompt there and type `httpd`, now run the code above.