# VBScript to run a php script from task scheduler but minimized

Tags: php, batch-file, vbscript

Yesterday I asked you this question;

[Running a batch file from windows task scheduler, but hidden or minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307638/running-a-batch-file-from-windows-task-scheduler-but-hidden-or-minimized)

The answer I selected was one suggesting I'd make a VBScript and use that, to run the original .bat file that executed the php script.

However, a comment on that suggestion, suggested to remove the .bat entirely and just run the php from the VBScript.
I decided that, that is what I wanted to do.

See here what I tried:

(This is written in followers.vbs)

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.php'", 0, True
```

What I have entered in task scheduler:

`Program / script:` `C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.vbs`

`Parameters:` `<blank>`

`Start in:` `C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2`

When I execute the .vbs through task scheduler, it does not do anything visually and I am assuming it is not doing anything non-visible either since the php script is not being executed. (the php sends me an email, and I am not receiving any)

The php script works fine executing it from a .bat file so it must be in my VBScript.

If anyone could take a quick look and see if I am doing anything wrong, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main change here is the file path without quotes.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.php", 0
```

Comment: how do I change the code so it runs the cmd minimized now? Do I simply add `, 0, True` after the last `)` ?

Comment: Sorry, Try removing the brackets then comma, 0. like this... WshShell.Run "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\FollowTrackerV2\followers.php", 0

Comment: isn't that exactly what I did in the code I posted in the OP ?

Comment: It's very close but slightly diff way of implementing it, and also calls the file (-f) as a path rather than string? if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission issue with the scheduled task, try setting the scheduled task to run as an administrator user.

Comment: Running it with highest permissions did not change anything.

Comment: OK, sorry - so I tried revising the VBscript to see how it works on my PC - I'll post the code into another answer for you...